# Getting an error with data reader

Tags: c#

am trying to get data from sql database using the datareader to put them in a combobox but am getting error in this code says :Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
the error is in the second part of the code in the while sentence. its a code for a form load.

```
class DataLoad
{  
    public SqlDataReader comboboxLoad()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Abdullah-PC;Initial Catalog=SmartPharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        com.CommandText = "select drugname from drugtab order by drugname";
        con.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();
        return dr;
    }
}



private void Smart_Pharmacy_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataLoad d = new DataLoad();
        SqlDataReader DR = d.comboboxLoad();

        while (DR.Read())
        {          
            DrugNameCombo.Items.Add(DR["drugname"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The method `comboboxLoad` is redundant. At least you should also add the code which add the items to the combobox. This will fix the error and also justifies the name of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed your connection with this line: `con.Close()`

You need to keep it open until you're finished reading from it. Try using a `using` statement:

```
// Open your connection here
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Abdullah-PC;Initial Catalog=SmartPharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
// The using statement declares that you want to use the SqlDataReader for a certain
// block of code. Can be used because it implements IDisposable
using(SqlDataReader DR = d.comboboxLoad(con)) {
    while (DR.Read())
    {          
        DrugNameCombo.Items.Add(DR["drugname"]);
    }
}
// When we reach here, the SqlDataReader will be disposed

// Could do some more work here

// Finally close the connection
con.Close();
```

You'll need to update your `comboboxLoad` to support this new way of working

```
public SqlDataReader comboboxLoad(SqlConnection con)
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "select drugname from drugtab order by drugname";
    return com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Or simply move the `DrugNameCombo.Items.Add`-code to the `comboboxLoad` method and make it `void`.

Comment: Or that...Which would make a lot more sense, but I think it highlights what was wrong with the original code if I keep the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are closing the connection `con.Close();` in your function `comboboxLoad()`. The reader needs an open connection to the database in order to work.

You should close the connection after you have disposed the dataReader.